# Dynamically building multiple projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to use Jenkins to dynamically search for `*.sln` files and trigger a build for each one.

I have a git repository with the following structure:

```
\Project1\Project1.sln
\Project2\Project2.sln
\Project3\Project3.sln
..
```

My current solution is to have two projects.

**Parent project:**

1. Add a build step: "Trigger/call builds on other projects"
2. Add a `ParameterFactory`: "For every matching file, invoke one build"
3. Search for `.sln` files and trigger a build for each matching file, with the filename set to: `SolutionFile`

**Child project:**

1. Use the environment variable "SolutionFile" to create the relative path to the solution file.

For example: `Project1.sln` becomes `Project1\Project1.sln`

2. Build the solution

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better / more robust solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution that I've been able to come up with so far.

There are two projects: top level is responsible for identifying the solution files, sub project builds the solution file.

**Top level project:**

1. Fetches the repository
2. Executes a windows powershell script to search for `.sln` files and creates a properties file for each one:

   ```
   $solutions = Get-ChildItem ./ -recurse -include *.sln 

   foreach ($solution in $solutions) {
       Write-Host "Identified solution for build: $($solution.name)"
       Resolve-Path -Relative $solution | foreach { "SolutionFile=$_" -replace  '\\', '\\' | Out-File "$($solution.name).properties" -Encoding ASCII} 
   }
   ```

   Note: I had to use encoding type ASCII, or the parameters would contain extra characters.
3. Build step: "Trigger/call builds on other projects" with a Parameter/Factories of "For every property file, invoke one build"

File pattern: `*.properties`

**Sub project:**

1. Setup with a parameter: `SolutionFile`, which is fed in by the properties file
2. Fetches the repository
3. Builds the solution file

Comment: I am using the same approach but the problem is when the downstream project is triggered , I don't see the SolutionFile parameter in the environment Variable